# How to list only root pages?

Tags: menus

I want to show only top level pages, without the dropdown. I am trying to set the depth to 0...

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'depth' => 0 ) );
```

But it generates:

```
<ul>
    <li class="current_page_item">
        <a href="http://www.test.com/" title="Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-11">
        <a href="http://www.test.com/about/" title="About">About</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li><a></a></li>  <!-- All sub-pages -->
            <li><a></a></li>  <!-- I want to skip them -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I list only the top level pages?

Answer (score 2):

Try `"depth"=>1`.  0 means "unlimited".

Comment: Didn't make any difference. I am using twentyeleven template...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I found this code:

```
<ul>
    <li<?php if ( is_home() || is_single() || is_search() || is_archive() ) { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<?php
    wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1');
?>
</ul>
```

[How To Highlight The Current Page In WordPress](http://www.vanseodesign.com/wordpress/hightlight-current-page-wordpress/)